# Excluding Text from jQuery animated Div

Tags: jquery, text, opacity

I am building a site using joomla, and I recently added a jQuery module that changes the opacity of the containing div when you hover over it. It contains text, and the text kinda looks cheesy because it loses opacity as well. So I was wondering, how I could target the div, but exclude the text so, that the text remains at 100% opacity.

Here is my code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>    
<script>jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
      //settings 
      var opacity = 0.5, toOpacity = 1, duration = 350; 
      //set opacity ASAP and events 
      jQuery('.opacity').css('opacity',opacity).hover(function() { 
          jQuery(this).fadeTo(duration,toOpacity); 
        }, function() { 
          jQuery(this).fadeTo(duration,opacity); 
        } 
      ); 
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Maybe you can select all the elements inside the div, excluding the ones that have text..

Comment: thats what I wanted to do, but I wouldnt know how to

Answer (score 4):

I've tried to use CSS to change the opacity of a container while maintaining totally opaque children and came to the conclusion that it can't be done, unfortunately.

What I suggest you do is have two divs positioned in the same location but only animate the opacity of one which works as a background layer.

Comment: Well that sucks! haha I guess I'll give it a try

Comment: Trust me, it sucks less than bashing your head against a wall - which is your other option.  Once you get used to the idea it's not as bad as it seems, although it is a shame that there is no other way. It can be managed fairly neatly.

Comment: Ok so I tried it out and the only problem is that once I hover over the text, it goes back to losing its opacity, as if I wasnt even hovering over the box.

Comment: What you can do is use a third top layer, with nothing visible, to trigger the hover.  This could have some nasty side effects to usability of the text though.  I've done this where it was purely graphical and it worked quite ok.

Comment: ohh ok, well I think it would work, but the text involved is a list with links. I dont think that you would be able to click on a link with that third layer on top would you?

Comment: take in mind guys that what is causing the hover effect is jQuery and not css

Comment: No, you'd have some trouble clicking on links.  Actually, you can probably do without the third layer and just make sure you use events on the text div.